# How to access Apache from an Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I am following [Tutorial: Installing a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html). My web server is started.

Now how do I access the website from my browser?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTES: If you play around with the free AWS account,  beware of the free quota. Once you exceed the quota, you are going be billed accordingly, e.g. once you exceed the 1GB download bandwidth from AWS.  Don't simply put multiple MB/GB of stuff there and try "capacity test".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a Public IP address to your Amazon EC2 instance. This can be done at startup by enabling **Auto-assign Public IP**, or it can be done later by assigning an Elastic IP address:

- Create an Elastic IP address in the Amazon EC2 console
- Associate it to your Amazon EC2 instance

You will also want to check that the **Security Group** associated with your instance is permitting inbound HTTP traffic (port 80).

Then, just put the IP address of your instance into your web browser.

Comment: can't instances access each other without Public IP even if I ignore to access via my browser?

Comment: If you are trying to access an Amazon EC2 instance from the Internet (eg from your home/office computer), then you will need to connect to the instance's public IP address. If you have a Direct Connect or VPN connection, you can access via private IP addresses because they are on the same 'virtual' network. Instances in the same VPC can also communicate with each other via private IP addresses.

Comment: I mean, I got I can't access via my browser due to IP issue but I have 40 EC2 instances which are able to connect each other. In that case if I install Webserver, can other instance talk to them?

Comment: If you have a different question to what was originally asked, please create a new StackOverflow Question. If this is related to the same topic, please Edit your question and provide more information to clarify your question.